# Find a crossing-free planar embedding of this graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

I've been spending far too long on this problem. I need to find a crossing-free planar embedding of this graph:

[image: G]

If there's a slight trick to it on what edge to move first, I'd prefer a hint instead.

Comment: Hint: Just look at $a$, $b$, $e$, and $f$.  How can you arrange those so that there are no crossings?  (On their subgraph - ignore the edges to $c$ and $d$ at first).  Then, swap the positions of $c$ and $d$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll post an answer with what I came up with. Feel free to post an answer if there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse the Microsoft Paint drawing, but here is what I came up with from the hint.

[image]